# C# Define local variable with an linq enumeration

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration

I need to define a local variable within a C# enumeration as I have an additional enumeration with that which is called several times creating inefficiencies. The code currently looks like this:

```
List<object> listData = new List<object>();
List<EmployeeAdvanced> workDataList = GetEmployeeWorkAdvancedData();
List<EmployeeBasic> employeeList = GetEmployeeBasicData();

listData .AddRange(
          from employee in employeeList
          where employee.SomeNumber  > 0
             select new{
             ID = employee.ID,
             SSN = employee.SSN
             StreetAddress = workDataList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ID==employee.EmployeeID).Address,
             Zipcode = workDataList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ID==employee.EmployeeID).Zipcode}
);
```

I actually have numerous enumerations of the workDataList list, but I'm selecting on the same item each time (EmployeeID). Is there some way I can just select my individual workDataList object once, then use it for all assignments within each individual from select loop.

The code above is a simplified version so names, data structures are just created for descriptive clarity.

Let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably, but it looks like some additional context is needed so we can see where reuse could occur.

Comment: There are plenty of samples how to do JOIN in Linq... Or you are looking for something else than JOIN (not completely clear from your sample).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx).

```
List<object> listData = new List<object>();
List<EmployeeAdvanced> workDataList = GetEmployeeWorkAdvancedData();
List<EmployeeBasic> employeeList = GetEmployeeBasicData();

listData .AddRange(
          from employee in employeeList
          where employee.SomeNumber  > 0
          let workData = workDataList.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ID==employee.EmployeeID)
             select new{
             ID = employee.ID,
             SSN = employee.SSN
             StreetAddress = workData.Address,
             Zipcode = workData.Zipcode}
);
```

Comment: Awesome, that did exactly what I needed it to do :)

Answer (score 1):

```
listData.AddRange(from employee in employeeList
                  where employee.SomeNumber  > 0
                      let employeeTmp = workDataList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == employee.EmployeeID)
                      select new {
                                    ID = employee.ID,
                                    SSN = employee.SSN
                                    StreetAddress = employeeTmp.Address,
                                    Zipcode = employeeTmp.Zipcode 
                                 }
);
```

You should use the [`let`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) keyword. [Here](http://www.codethinked.com/the-linq-quot3bletquot3b-keyword) is a thoroughly explanation of the usage.